# CSS wrap text exactly to width

Tags: css

I'm using `white-space:nowrap;` to keep my text in one line. But the text is long and goes beyond the element. How to wrap the text exactly to the width of an element?

To understand more clearly what I mean, see [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4amP/1/).

Update: [another JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4amP/8/) to show more clearly what I need.

Comment: Do you want to expand the width of the element to fit the text or wrap the text to fit inside the elements width?

Comment: I want to wrap the text to fit inside the elements width

Comment: Just take the `white-space: nowrap` off then.

Comment: But how to keep the text in one line?

Comment: Wait a minute, what do you expect the text to do when on one line it DOESN'T fit inside your element? Shrink? Wrap? Expand the box? You've got a unique problem here.

Comment: @megas you need to explain clearly what you want.

Comment: @Marko, yes shrink the text to fit to elements width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS long as you've set the width of the element, just take the whitespace:no-wrap off, and it will wrap the text exactly to the width of the element.

**edit**

OK -- here's what you need:

```
div {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  width:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:1em;
}
```

Comment: But the text will have several lines, i need only one.

Comment: Got it -- ok, see the ammended answer.  Using the div from your example, I added overflow and height.  And also, I got rid of the css for the paragraph (`<p>`)

Answer (score 0):

Take off `white-space: nowrap;` and put on `word-spacing: -1px;`

I'm not sure how each browser is going to react, so you may need to adjust the word-spacing property.

Comment: I will get several lines for my text, I need only one line.

Comment: I'm confused, are you looking for the box to expand the the exact width of the text it contains, or you want the text to wrap exactly at the edge of the box which contains it? If you want the prior, remove `white-space: nowrap;` and add `display: inline-block` to your div declaration.